# Android app detect event when app brought to the foreground?

Tags: android

Current situation and problem :

I have more than 10 activity in my app and AppController class extend by Application class. currently successfully detect onbackground event when an app is sent to the background using onTrimMemory (TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND) in AppController class.

Now I want to detect event when app again come in foreground.

Is there any method or event like onTrimMemory ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally we found the solution !

Try this example
http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html

Connect Application with activity life cycle and check isVisibleState in onTrimMemory.
i.e.

```
implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, ComponentCallbacks2 {
```

And in onTrimMemory

```
@Override
       public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
              if (stateOfLifeCycle.equals("Stop")) {
                     wasInBackground = true;
              }
              super.onTrimMemory(level);
       }
```